# Statements about vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

[image]

I am trying to explain which statements are true or false:

(i) It is false and I provide a counterexample with vectors that do not span but are linearly independent.
(ii) This seems to be false since some vectors can be multiples of each other.
(iii) I am not sure about this one, shouldn't it be less or equal rather than equal?
(iv) True by intuition. How do I explain why?
(v)  False. Matrix A can be singular hence have no inverse.
(vi) Not sure

Comment: (i) is true. For (iii), yes, it would be correct if it was $\le$, the zero operator is a counterexample. For (iv), you need a proof, not intuition. if $A^m = 0$, then $(A^{-1})^m A^m = I \neq 0$. (v) is true. If $A^k =I$ for some $k$ then clearly $A^{k-1}$ is the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

For (vi), all you know is that $A^4-I = 0$, hence the roots of the minimal (and
hence characteristic) polynomial satisfy $z^4 = 1$.

Even though $z^4-1=(z^2-1)(z^2+1)$, you cannot conclude that either $z^2-1$ or
$z^2+1$ are factors of the minimal polynomial (which would be the case if $A^2=I$ or $A^2 = -I$).

It could be $(z-1)(z-i)$ since this factors $z^4-1$. This suggests a
simple diagonal two dimensional counterexample...

Answer (score 1):

i) Is true: maybe you didn't see that you have **n** vectors, in a Space $V$ of dimension **n**. If you could have $n$ linearly independent vectors which do not span in a n-dimensional Space, then you could extend the collection to a base, and since now you have $n+k$ vectors ($k\in \mathbb{N}$) then your space should be $n+k$ dimensional, which is an absurd

Answer (score 1):

For (iv), if $A$ is invertible, then $(A^n)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^n$ for all $n$.  If $A$ is invertible and $A^m = O_{n,n}$, then $I_n = (A^m)^{-1}\cdot A^m = (A^m)^{-1} \cdot O_{n,n} = O_{n,n}$, a contradiction.

For (v), if $A^k = I_n$, then $ A^{k-1}\cdot A = A \cdot A^{k-1} = I_n$, exhibiting $A^{k-1} = A^{-1}$.

For (vi), factor $ A^4 - I = ( A^2 - I )\times (A^2 + I)$

Comment: In (vi), factoring doesn't help.